# Can clang-format align "using enum" C++20 statement inside switch expression?

Tags: c++, enums, switch-statement, c++20, clang-format

Assuming the following snippet:

```
switch (val) {
case SomeEnum::SomeValue:
    doSomething(val);
case SomeEnum::SomeOtherValue:
    doSomethingElse(val);
default:
    break;
}
```

in C++20 we can instead use:

```
switch (val) {
using enum SomeEnum;
case SomeValue:
    doSomething(val);
case SomeOtherValue:
    doSomethingElse(val);
default:
    break;
}
```

However, clang-format 15 and 17 both seem to indent the `using enum` statement in a weird way not matching the rest of code (with `IndentCaseLabels` set to `false` to align `case` on the same level as `switch`):

```
switch (val) {
    using enum SomeEnum;
case SomeValue:
    doSomething(val);
case SomeOtherValue:
    doSomethingElse(val);
default:
    break;
}
```

Is there any way to configure clang-format to keep the same indentation for `using enum` as for `case` conditions? I could not find anything relevant in the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html).

Comment: Not sure I understand correctly. Do you want **all** the code inside the **body** of the `switch`-statement to be on the same indentation level as the `case:`-**labels**? Or do you only want `using enum`-declarations to be the sole exception? Because, for example, if it were a function's body (not a `switch`-statement), would you really put the `using enum`-declaration to the left, like a `goto`-label? Doesn't seem logical. To me, labels feel special, the rest of the body code feels regular.

Comment: As the question says, I'm looking for `using enum` to be on the same indentation level as the `case` conditions/labels, so moved to the left. As for me it has similar meaning as `case` checks as it's used to simplify them. It's not regular code, just something applying to the formatting of the `switch` expression. Thanks.

Comment: It bothers me too, but aligning it like the case labels wouldn't really make much sense. Imagine you have a using enum directive _below_ a case label (not related to the values you're switching over). You wouldn't want that one to be aligned like the case labels, but there is no syntactic difference between the two.